# Find $a$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq\mu+c)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}[|X-\mu|^n]}{a}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $c>0$ and $n>0$ and let $X$ be a random variable with a finite mean $\mu$ and for which $\mathbb{E}[|X-\mu|^n]<\infty$. Find $a$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq\mu+c)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}[|X-\mu|^n]}{a}$

**My thinking**

This appears to be a variation of Markov's inequality, where an exponent was added to the expectation.
$$\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq c)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}[X-\mu]}{c}$$
I guess the question becomes, if we change the expectation, how would that change $c$. Can I get hints on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: Is there a random variable that applying Markov's inequality to would give $\mathbb{E}[|X-\mu|^n]/a$ on the righthand side?

Answer (score 3):

$P(X \geq \mu+c) \leq P(|X-\mu| >c)=P(|X-\mu|^{n} >c^{n})\leq \frac {E(|X-\mu|)^{n}} {c^{n}}$ so we can take $a=c^{n}$.